# JS-enhanced form components don't respect sorting/filtering in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ckeditor, vue-component, tinymce

I am working on a basic to-do app in Vue in which each item in a `v-for` list contains some "normal" form fields (like text inputs and checkboxes), and some "special" form fields—Vue components for WYSIWYG editors like [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/) or [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html), and tag inputs like [Tagify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tagify-vue).

**The problem:** When I sort or filter my list, the "normal" form fields sort and filter correctly, but the "special" form field values stay where they are. For example, when alphabetically sorting two items where the **Title** is a standard text input and **Description** is a "special" field (e.g. TinyMCE or CKEditor), it behaves like this:

---

#### Before sorting:

**Title input:** Zed
**Description:** Zed description

**Title input:** Alpha
**Description:** Alpha description

---

#### After sorting:

**Title input:** Alpha `⬅ Correct`
**Description:** Zed description `⬅ Hasn't moved!`

**Title input:** Zed `⬅ Correct`
**Description:** Alpha description `⬅ Hasn't moved!`

---

Here is a simplified example using TinyMCE: https://codepen.io/ericpedia/pen/VwjQXqV

This happens with all the JS-enhanced form fields I have tried. (For all of them I'm using their official Vue components.) Many involve some kind of initialization in the `mounted` hook; I have tried moving logic to the `updated` hook and/or using `$nextTick`, but see the same behavior, and wonder if this should even be necessary to re-set on every sort and filter. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common issue, You must set a unique key `:key` in your `v-for` to avoid this kind of problems, I don't know how `tinymce` works but you should know that you have to watch and re-init your `tinymce` if the `id` has been changed.